# Stopping a Distributed Ruby Service

Tags: ruby, distributed, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8, drb

I have a script that starts up a DRb service, before spawning a handler object and waiting via `DRb.thread.join`. I would like the script to run until explicitly killed, so I added

```
trap "INT" do
  DRb.stop_service
end
```

which successfully stops the DRb service and exits under Ruby 1.8, but under 1.9 seems to deadlock (on OS X 10.6.7). Sampling the process shows a couple of threads spinning in `semaphore_wait_signal_trap`.

I assume that I'm doing something wrong in the way I'm calling `stop_service`, but I'm not sure what. Could anyone give me any pointers around how to correctly go about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I think I have found the solution. If I replace the original code with

```
begin
  DRb.thread.join
rescue Interrupt
ensure
  DRb.stop_service
end
```

The Ctrl-C works and stops the service.

Answer (score 0):

`DRb.thread.join` makes the calling thread wait for DRb execution thread to end.
If you want to catch `INT` signal I'd rather go with the following code instead.

```
$execute = true
DRb.start_service

Signal.trap("INT") { $execute = false }
while $execute
  sleep 1
end
DRb.stop_service
```

Note that there is no `DRb.thread.join` in this case.
Also catching the signal is the preferred way instead of rescuing the Interrupt exception.